# Web Service: Specifying XML Serialization element names for generic types

Tags: web-services, generics, xml-serialization

I've created a web service that uses a generic type `Response<TCode, TData>` and so I'm ending up with elements like

- ResponseOfResponseCodeUserData
- ResponseOfResponseCodeArrayOfRightData

etc.

Functionally works just fine but I'm wondering if there's a way to name these particular elements?

**EDIT:**

Here's an example.

```
[return: XmlElement("AuthenticationResponse")]
[WebMethod]
public Response<ResponseCode, AuthenticationData> AuthenticateProcess(string ProcessName, string Password)
{
   // ... Code ...
}
```

Still returns

```
<ResponseOfResponseCodeAuthenticationData (...) >
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help if you were to show some code.

Still, look at the [XmlElementAttribute] attribute, which allows you to specify the element name. If your issue is with return values, then you will need to use

```
[return: XmlRoot("ReturnElementName")]
[WebMethod]
public int MyWebMethod() { ... }
```

Comment: Ah, the attribute is XmlRoot. Updated appropriately.